# Looping Objects of Object with handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple node.js app that returns the following json.

```
{
  computers: {
   john: {
     cpu: "intel",
     ram: "8MB",
     hd: "1TB"
   },
   jane: {
     cpu: "intel",
     ram: "12MB",
     hd: "500GB"
   },
   mary: {
     cpu: "intel",
     ram: "8MB",
     hd: "500GB"
   }
  }
}
```

in my index.hbs file I have the following.

```
{{#each computers}}
   {{#each this}}
      {{cpu}} {{ram}} {{hd}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I would like the get the following result.

John: intel, 8MB, 1TB
jane: intel, 12MB, 500GB
etc..

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would transform the JSON response to an array and then iterate over that array in the template. Do you have access to the back-end code to do that?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to back-end codes. Let me look up how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create nested `each`. Simply using [paths](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) combined with `@key` to get current key of iterating object will do.

```
{{#each computers}}
  {{@key}}: {{./cpu}}, {{./ram}}, {{./hd}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks Chay22,  I'll this a try and let you know this works or not.

Comment: I'm getting this (0: , ,) returned. Any suggestions?

Comment: That could prolly means, the object given doesn't in equal form with the object you've provided in question. You can actually try with handlebars live here http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: This work as expected on tryhandlebarsjs.com, there must be something with the code, thanks for your help!